# SQLITE - setting the version of a new database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have used this example to create a database that I copy over on a fresh install

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Problem I have now is I have now done some updates to the database and I asummed I also do this updates to the master file within the build so the users always get the most update version on new install

I have a different class that deals with all the db calls query statements.

I have set this line

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
```

On a fresh install now the database is copied over correctly but when the query class calls the databasehelper again the onupgrade() method is called and tries to update to the latest version and the app crashes as it is trying to do upgrades that cannot be done

I was under the understanding that the following set the database version on fresh installs or is this wrong. If so how do I set the database version for new installs

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

just for completness here is a sample of the onupgrade()

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        dbUpgrade = new DatabaseUpgrades(context);

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Calling onupgrade db");
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG + " : " + DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion);

        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Updating to Version 2");
            dbUpgrade.upgradeDB2(db);
            oldVersion++;
        }
}
```

Question what version is the new database set to on a fresh install and how can you overwrite it if it is not version 5

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        /* ... */
}
```

I put below `getWritableDatabase()` source code and as you see it won't call `onUpgrade()` unless the version in the db file is not equal to current new version which you pass in the constructor(`version != mNewVersion` line). So either your database file is not overwritten or version number in your new database is wrong. Please check it.

```
/**
 * Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.
 * Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
 * method every time you need to write to the database.  Make sure to call
 * {@link #close} when you no longer need it.
 *
 * <p>Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this operation
 * to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.</p>
 *
 * @throws SQLiteException if the database cannot be opened for writing
 * @return a read/write database object valid until {@link #close} is called
 */
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen() && !mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
        return mDatabase;  // The database is already open for business
    }

    if (mIsInitializing) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getWritableDatabase called recursively");
    }

    // If we have a read-only database open, someone could be using it
    // (though they shouldn't), which would cause a lock to be held on
    // the file, and our attempts to open the database read-write would
    // fail waiting for the file lock.  To prevent that, we acquire the
    // lock on the read-only database, which shuts out other users.

    boolean success = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase.lock();
    try {
        mIsInitializing = true;
        if (mName == null) {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.create(null);
        } else {
            db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(mName, 0, mFactory);
        }

        int version = db.getVersion();
        if (version != mNewVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (version == 0) {
                    onCreate(db);
                } else {
                    onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                }
                db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }

        onOpen(db);
        success = true;
        return db;
    } finally {
        mIsInitializing = false;
        if (success) {
            if (mDatabase != null) {
                try { mDatabase.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
                mDatabase.unlock();
            }
            mDatabase = db;
        } else {
            if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase.unlock();
            if (db != null) db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
You can check version in your new database file with the following query:

```
PRAGMA user_version;
```

It should return `5` in your case.

Comment: ok, little confused. How do I set the Version of the Database on fresh install? or should it be set to Version 5 and I am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Execute `PRAGMA user_version;` in SQqlite Browser, what do you get?

Comment: sorry still rather noobish when it comes to SQLITE. what do you mean run that query. within a log statement or somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: If you don't get `5` then do this: `PRAGMA user_version = 5;`

Comment: When you open your database with "SQLite Database Browser" program, there is a tab called "Execute SQL". You put `PRAGMA user_version;` there and click "Execute Query"

Comment: You can see the screenshot in the link you posted

Comment: So let me get this right. The Database file that I copy across has a master version on it. I have not changed this so it is always version 1. So I need to run the PRAGMA user_version = 5; and save the file and re-apply the file to the build. Thanks

Comment: oh, thanks. Appears to work now. Thanks very much I did not know I had to set the database version on the file itself

Comment: Um, normally, the database version should be set by SQLiteOpenHelper when you call its constructor with a new db version, right? If the version parameter you pass to the constructor is higher than what the db already has, it will call `onUpgrade()` and if successful it will update the db version number, right? You should not have to modify the db version in the db file itself.

Answer (score 0):

It got a method called 
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
     perform your upgrade stuff here. . . 
}

if your are using SQLiteOpenHelper class then only you can override this method.

Comment: I have this already with if oldversion == 1 etc etc. I have 4 methods being called in the onupgrade depending on the version of the database but all these are being called on a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

just create a

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        onUpgrade(db, 0, DATABASE_VERSION);
```