# How to ship app with pre-filled table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy

I'm developing an app in which I create a database with several tables:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String table = "CREATE TABLE users(";
        table += "_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table += "cat TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table += "city TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table += "country TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table += "addr TEXT,";

        String table2 = "CREATE TABLE special(";
        table2 += "idspec TEXT PRIMARY KEY);";

        String table3 = "CREATE TABLE places(";
        table3 += "id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table3 += "text TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table3 += "data TEXT NOT NULL,";
        table3 += "user TEXT REFERENCES users(_id));";

        String table4 = "CREATE TABLE average(";
        table4 += "user TEXT PRIMARY KEY,";
        table4 += "place INTEGER NOT NULL,";
        table4 += "avg REAL NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(table);
        db.execSQL(table2);
        db.execSQL(table3);
        db.execSQL(table4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

I want to add further table that has about 70 entries that I will read in other classes. So, how to add a pre-filled table?
Maybe, there is a best way to reach the same purpose, sorry if I don't know it.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I searched before to post and none asks about shipping an android app with a pre-filled table. I create the database on app launch, so i do not need to bundle a database, i want just to have some data already filled in one table of the same database.

Comment: Very easy, then: in the `onCreate()`, method simply check if there are no records. Then execute your inserts, under a transaction.

Comment: I'm sure it is the right way. Could you add an answer with an example?

Comment: `I want to add further table`. This should be done in the `onUpgrade()` method, setting the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant to a higher value.

Comment: Rename your **DB_VERSION** constant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648131/sqlite-setting-the-version-of-a-new-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate(), method simply check if there are no records.

I.e: do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

and check if the record count is 0

```
int count = cur.getCount();
```

If count is 0, then execute your inserts, under a transaction.
Note: I pass a context to my function, which I call `ctx`

This is the core part of the function

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try
    {
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        // Start the transaction
        db.beginTransaction();

        // Fill the table
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users () values ()");
        // ... more inserts...

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch (final SQLiteException se)
    {
        System.out.println
        (
            ctx.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\n" +
                "Could not import to the database"
        );
        se.printStackTrace();
        result = 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        // End the transaction
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
```

**[EDIT]**

Then I read: `I want to add further table`.

This (altering an existing database structure) has to be done in the `onUpgrade()` method, setting the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant to a higher value (in order to make the `onUpgrade()` method fire).

Comment: The app isn't released yet... why i can't add this pre-filled table in onCreate() method?

Comment: Well, just don't take in accout the **EDIT** part and you're fine. I added it reading "I want to **add** a table". Simply delete the database from your `/data/data/...` path and re-run the app.

Comment: Ehm... do i have to create a new method (with your code) in my SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Comment: Not necessarily. Adviced, though. I'd call it `preFillTable(Context ctx, String tableName){...}`

Comment: So i have to call it when i create Database. Should'n i create it in OnCreate() method in which i create the other tables?

Comment: You execute the code in the `onCreate()`. Either 1 - copy/paste my code **directly** inside your `onCreate()` OR 2 - create a new method, call it whatever, copy/paste my code inside it, call this one in your `onCreate()`. **2** is cleaner than having a lot of code in your `onCreate()`

Comment: I see, i'm writing it... stay tuned :D ehm... how to use result?

Comment: It's self included. the method is a **void**. OR you can make it reurn a **boolean** just to inform you if it crashed or executed fine.

Comment: I'm experiencing some problems... in OnCreate() method i don't have any Context, so when i call preFillTable() i don't have any ctx to pass to it.

Comment: Pass it `getApplicationContext()`. Or do (as I do, because I use it **everywhere**) something like `private static Context ctx = null;` followed by `ctx = getApplicationContext();`. If you do that in the method, don't pass it the context and add this line: `private static Context ctx =  getApplicationContext();`

Comment: It is not an Activity, it is my own class that implements SQLiteOpenHelper. I have the Context in my own constructor. Can i save it to a field and then use it in onCreate()? Is this a good way?

Comment: I'm also using such a class (I called it `CLS_DB`), no problem at all. I declare `ctx` in my main Activity (which uses the method in the Class). And pass it the `ctx` object: `CLS_DB.myMethod(ctx, "Users");`.

Comment: I got some problems because i use an AsyncTask to populate the other tables. So i had to add your method in the AsyncTask and now it works. Thank you for your great support.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SQLiteAssetHelper for shipping your app with prefilled data,here is the link for repository https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper
In your app simply  call the constructor as

```
public Yourclassname(Context context) 
{
super(context,Database_Name,null, Database_Version);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to add a full database in the assets folder, just pre-fill one table of the database.